# Angular 7 Class / structs / interfaces shared among projects

Tags: angular

I am working in multiple angular apps that share the same custom objects. I am trying to do it, but I have no idea how to accomplish it.

I have tried creating a library, but when I try to include the classes in the export section, angular tells me that I cannot add a reference but a instanciated object.

Then, I tried creating a .ts file at the same level of the Projects folder, but when compilating, angular tells me that it has to be in the root folder.

> BUILD ERROR error TS6059: File
>   'angular/projects/Classes/Interfaces.ts' is not under 'rootDir'

This is a sample of I am trying to inculde and reuse.

```
 export class Room { 
  constructor(
    public cod: string,
    public name: string,
    public room: ApiRoomRate,
    public p: Number
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm. It's not really clear the exact use case for you, but you basically need to compile the typescript files to javascript files, generate the typings, package them and publish the package to some (private?) npm registry that you can reuse now in various projects and it's also versioned.

Here is an article talking about this: https://itnext.io/step-by-step-building-and-publishing-an-npm-typescript-package-44fe7164964c

The main thing is to enable declarations in `tsconfig.json` so it's easier to reuse the package in a `typescript` context.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this. My scenario is basically, In c# for instance, I usually create a project (DLL) that include all my structs, and classes definitions and I import that DLL into the other projects, so I have my classes and methods everywhere. I am looking forward doind the same with angular.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.

It was easier of what I woul've thought. I only had to add `export * from './Classes/Structures';` to my public_api.ts file and that made the trick.